# Pygame font error

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

So I decided to start making a game and I was testing it a bit and then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TheAviGame.py", line 15, in <module>
    font = pygame.font.Font(None,25)
pygame.error: font not initialized
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong so far...
Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
blue = (25,25,112)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
groundcolor = (139,69,19)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1336,768))
pygame.display.set_caption("TheAviGame")
direction = 'none'
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
img = pygame.image.load('player.bmp')
imgx = 1000
imgy = 100
font = pygame.font.Font(None,25)
def mts(text, textcolor, x, y):
    text = font.render(text, True, textcolor)
    gamedisplay.blit(text, [x,y])
def gameloop():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.pygame == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.RIGHT:
                    imgx += 10
        gameDisplay.fill(blue)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
gameloop()
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You never initialized `pygame` and `pygame.font` after importing:

```
# imports

pygame.init() # now use display and fonts
```

Comment: If you call `pygame.init` you don't need to *also* call `pygame.font.init` (though it's innocuous to do so, it's not required) since `pygame.init` does that on your behalf.  You call `pygame.font.init` to do any kind of font work before initializing the whole of `pygame`, if you so desire.  As http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init explains, "You may want to initalise the different modules seperately to speed up your program or to not use things your game does not.".

Comment: Yes, I know. I was simply pointing that he has not initialized pygame for the use of the display. The font is a secondary issue.

Comment: I tried blitting in img and what I did was under the while true: I did gameDisplay.blit(img, (100,100)) and then pygame.display.update() under it but it it now it like flashes a ton... @MalikBrahimi

Answer (score 4):

In order to use some pygame modules, either pygame or that specific module has to be initialised *before* you start using them - this is what the error message is telling you.

To initialize pygame:

```
import pygame
...
pygame.init()
```

To initialize a specific library (eg font):

```
import pygame
...
pygame.font.init()
```

In most cases, you will want to initialise all of pygame, so use the first version. In general, I would place this at the top of my code, just after importing pygame

Answer (score 0):

You put `None` in the font:

```
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
```

You can’t do that.
You have to put a type of font there.

And you should call `pygame.init()`.

Comment: As far as I know, `None` works. It just loads the default font of Pygame.